# if page link is like test.html?a=1&b=2 then how load function will work getting value of a and load particular div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html page is:

```
test.php?a=1&b=2
```

Send response to `post.php` then `abc.php` when response callback to post.php and then test.php.
(`test.php` -> `post.php` -> `abc.php`) sending
(`abc.php` -> `post.php` -> `test.php`) receiving
`test.php` is main page
`post.php` and `abc.php` both are jquery response page

How will the load function work including `$_GET` value in my page?

When I use this:

```
$("#div").load("test.php #div")
```

**Result:** it just load div with data and not getting `a` and `b` value

```
$.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url: "abc.php",
     data: dataString
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    $("#div").load("test.php?a="+xx+ "#div");
}
```

in `abc.php` page i have send `a` value in echo like `echo $xx;`
this echo is just to get `a` value response data is in session with this `$("#div").load("test.php #div")` am getting session data as it is cart items on particular div

**but when i used something like this**

```
   $("#div").load("test.php?a="+xx+ "#div");
```

**Result :** it load `whole page` in that `div` instead of `just div load` but with this i am getting value of `a`

i want `a` value and `only div load` not `whole page`

Comment: can you show what exactly your PHP returns?

Comment: I have tried to clarify what your question is but is still quite unclear. You might want to try and explain yourself more clearly if you want useful help.

Answer (score 0):

you need use $("#div").html('whatever the div content shouldbe').

Comment: i want to append the data ..my response back data is in session...using echo is just to get "a" value